# Make get requests with libsoup in vala building with Flatpak

Tags: vala, flatpak

I'm trying to use soup for a http GET request in vala, but always return a Status code 6, in the manifest file I have the permission "--share=network"

I don't know what the problem is, if I need to have an additional permission to make server requests or is it part of the security of flatpak?

```
// Vala code
var session = new Soup.Session();
var uri = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/var message = new Soup.Message ("GET",session.queue_message (message, (sess, mess) =>
    // Process the result:
    print ("Status Code: %u\n", mess.status_code);
    print ("Message length: %lld\n", mess.response_body.length);
}

// Manifest file
{
    "app-id": "com.github.calo001.fondo",
    "base": "io.elementary.
    "base-version": "juno",
    "runtime": "org.freedesktop.Platform",
    "sdk": "org.freedesktop.Sdk",
    "runtime-version": "18.08",
    "command": "com.github.calo001.fondo",
    "finish-args": [
        /* X11 + XShm */
        "--share=ipc", "--socket=x11",
        /* Wayland */
        "--socket=wayland",
        /* Network */
        "--share=network",
        /* dconf */
        "--filesystem=xdg-run/dconf", "--filesystem=~/.config/dconf:ro",
        "--talk-name=ca.desrt.dconf", "--env=DCONF_USER_CONFIG_DIR=.config/dconf"
    ],
    "modules": [
        {
            "name": "fondo",
            "buildsystem": "meson",
            "config-opts": ["--buildtype=release"],
            "sources":[
               {
                   "type": "git",
                   "url": "https://github.com/calo001/fondo.git"
               }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [soup-status.h](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libsoup/blob/master/libsoup/soup-status.h) status code 6 is `SOUP_STATUS_SSL_FAILED`. So the first thing to try would be using `http` instead of `https`. By the way your `Soup.Message` sample is showing `"POST"`, but you say you are trying to make a GET request. You could also use [`Soup.Message.get_https_status`](https://valadoc.org/libsoup-2.4/Soup.Message.get_https_status.html) to get more details on the HTTPS request failure.

Comment: Hey thanks AlThomas, it works, I already corrected the example code to a "GET" request, I also needed to try another API (unsplash) where I also add the property ssl_strict = false to work correcty;